# Matlab check if input is nonezero

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

working on a project and have to make sure the input in a textbox meets a requirement for both being numeric, but also not being equal to zero. So far this is my code:

```
function minValue_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to edit10 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'String') returns contents of edit10 as text
%        str2double(get(hObject,'String')) returns contents of edit10 as a     double
user_entry_X = str2double(get(hObject,'string'));
if isnan(user_entry_X)
 errordlg('You must enter a numeric value','Error!','modal')
 uicontrol(hObject)
return
end
```

Another question is, I have two textboxes, minValue and maxValue. How can I also make sure that the data in `maxValue > minValue`? (Values are used in a for loop, and I thought checking before hand and showing an error would be better.)

Comment: What is your question? Where is the problem implementing that?

Comment: @Daniel Question is how to make sure input is not zero but is also numeric.  And is it possible to call this CallBack from a different function or on a button press?

Comment: @Link For the second part, in maxValueText_callback and minValueText_callback, why not check against limits, and adjust the limits of the other according to the current value that has just changed?

Answer (score 1):

So, if I understand correctly, you should change the lines:

```
if isnan(user_entry_X)
    errordlg('You must enter a numeric value','Error!','modal');
```

to be:

```
if isnan(user_entry_X) || user_entry_X == 0
    errordlg('You must enter a non-zero numeric value','Error!','modal');
```

For the second part of the question, I don't understand the difficulty. Just type:

```
if maxValue > minValue
    ...
end
```

Comment: For 2nd part I need to check when they're entered in either textbox, unsure how to do that.

Comment: `isnan` is required because that's what `str2double` returns for invalid inputs. `isnumeric` returns `true` for `NaN` and `str2double` only returns scalar numeric values  (for string inputs) by definition.

Comment: @horchler Do you have an idea of what to do then?

Comment: Fixed. Thanks @horchler. FYI, this solution accepts complex numbers. If you don't want to accept complex input, change the test to `if isnan(user_entry_X) || ~isreal(user_entry_X) || user_entry_X == 0`

Comment: Do you also want to check for >= 0, or is negative input valid?

Comment: @NigelDavies, as stated in the question, the OP is looking for **nonzero** input.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use

```
errordlg('You must enter a numeric value','Error!','modal')
h = uicontrol(hObject)
uiwait(h)
```

So the error dialogue stays open until the user acknowledges. (I fell into the trap beleiving, possibly from windows programming, that 'modal' creates this behaviour.)